# Java - 2D Array manipulation is affecting the inverse of the index

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, chess

I am trying to learn Java by applying my knowledge and making a Java Chess Game. For the moment it is strictly text. In my program I have a function which allows me to move a piece. All the pieces are stored in a 2D array called board. The problem however lies in this function when I am trying to move a piece. If I move a piece ("Rook") from `board[7][0]` to `board[6][0]` for some reason the opposite of this (`board[0][0]` to `board[1][0]`) is also getting moved.

Here is the board without any modifications show with `displayBoard()`:

```
ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK, 
PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, 
ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK,
```

Board after piece has been moved:

```
null, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK, 
ROOK, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
ROOK, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, 
null, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK,
```

Only the lower left rook should've been moved.
Board.Java Class:

```
public class Board {
    public Pieces[][] board = new Pieces[8][8];

    private Pieces[] MainLine = new Pieces[]{Pieces.ROOK, Pieces.KNIGHT, Pieces.BISHOP, Pieces.QUEEN, Pieces.KING, Pieces.BISHOP, Pieces.KNIGHT, Pieces.ROOK};
    private Pieces[] BishopLine = new Pieces[]{Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN};

    public Board(){
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void resetBoard() {
        board = new Pieces[8][8];
        board[0] = MainLine;
        board[board.length - 1] = MainLine;
        board[1] = BishopLine;
        board[board.length - 2] = BishopLine;
    }

    public void displayBoard() {
        for(int rank = 0; rank < board.length; rank++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for(int file = 0; file < board.length; file ++) {
                System.out.print(board[rank][file] + ", ");
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public Pieces getPiece(int rank, int file) {
        return board[rank][file];
    }

    public void movePiece(int rank, int file, int newRank, int newFile) {
        Pieces temp = getPiece(rank, file);
        board[rank][file] = null;
        board[newRank][newFile] = temp;
    }
}
```

In my Main Class I create a new instance of the board, display it, move a piece `movePiece(7, 0, 6, 0)` and then display the board again. I believe the main issue is in the Board.java class and I have no clue what is wrong or why other Indexes are being affected. Could anyone explain to me why this is happening or how to better manipulate the 2D `board` array in order to further accomplish my goal, which is to move a piece to a given position without affecting any other pieces.

EDIT: Added extra code requested -

Main.Java creates an instance of game where other conditions will occur in the future however it is Game.java which holds the direct reference to Board.Java as it inherits from it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();

        game.displayBoard();
        game.movePiece(7, 0, 6, 0);
        game.displayBoard();

    }
}
```

Game.java simply calls super which creates the board. It will later hold extra functionality:

```
public class Game extends Board {
    public Game() {
        super();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Please show the code where you call movePiece

Comment: Are you ignoring the fact that the pawn disappears when you move the rook (for now)?

Comment: Yes, for now I simply want the  functionality of moving a piece. Conditions will later be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is in the constructor for `Board` more specifically the `resetBoard()` method, you are initializing the first row to the same array as the last row and similarly, the second row is referring to the same array as the second to last row:

```
private void resetBoard() {
    board = new Pieces[8][8];

    // board[0] is a reference to MainLine so if we change move
    // into or out of board[0] MainLine will be affected and 
    // we won't be able to start with a fresh board by calling boardReset()
    // board[0] = MainLine;

    // Initialize the first row to a fresh array every time we call
    // reset.
    board[0] = new Pieces[] { 
        Pieces.ROOK, Pieces.KNIGHT, Pieces.BISHOP, Pieces.QUEEN, 
        Pieces.KING, Pieces.BISHOP, Pieces.KNIGHT, Pieces.ROOK
    };

    // This makes the last line and
    // the first line point to the same array
    // You need to create a new array that is a deep copy
    // of the array.
    // board[board.length - 1] = MainLine; 

    // Create new array by copying the original array
    board[board.length - 1] = Arrays.copyOf(board[0], board[0].length);

    // Similarly
    //board[1] = BishopLine;
    Arrays.fill(board[1], Pieces.PAWN);
    board[board.length - 2] = Arrays.copyOf(board[1], board[1].length);

    // You don't need member variables MainLine and BishopLine
    // and you can remove them if you want.
}
```

Now both rows are pointing to different arrays. When you call `movePiece(7, 0, 6, 0)` You should see

```
ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK, 
PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, 
ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK, 



ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK, 
PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
ROOK, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, 
null, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK,
```

Comment: That did the trick! Interesting to see that Java works that way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RafaelPiloto10 glad I could help! Interesting project you are working on, I really got a kick out of seeing the board change!

Comment: Thanks! Can't wait to learn more about Java and all of its interesting features, even if I have to stare at my code for an hour or two hopelessly wondering why my code isn't working the way I think it should. It will all be worth it in the end :D Cheers!

Comment: @RafaelPiloto10 I've edited my answer to update `resetBoard()` becuase it dawned on me that if you plan to call this method explicitly and not only in the constructor, it won't really update the board since the contents of `MainLine` and `BishopLine` were getting altered. With the new changes you shouldn't have that issue. You can ignore the edit if you don't plan to call `resetBoard()` explicitly. I've added more comments explaining why the changes.

Comment: I took Sachin's advice in setting board[0] to a new array of `Pieces[]`. I tested the scenario and I don't seem to be having any issues for the moment, however if I do have any issues again I'll take a look at your code and see what I can do differently. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem lie in resetBoard() function. Here you are using same object reference for both the players chess pieces. So, as java is pass by value both board[7][0] and board[0][0] are referring to same object and when one change so is the other.

For simplicity you can try something like below

Or create a copy constructor in pieces class and call from resetBoard method

Or override clone() method in pieces class to do a deep copy of object so that two reference will not point a common object.

or use Arrays.copyOf(arrayToCopy,length) to create a new copy.

```
 private void resetBoard() {
    board = new Pieces[8][8];
    board[0] = new Pieces[]{Pieces.ROOK, Pieces.KNIGHT, Pieces.BISHOP, Pieces.QUEEN, Pieces.KING, Pieces.BISHOP, Pieces.KNIGHT, Pieces.ROOK};
    board[board.length - 1] = new Pieces[]{Pieces.ROOK, Pieces.KNIGHT, Pieces.BISHOP, Pieces.QUEEN, Pieces.KING, Pieces.BISHOP, Pieces.KNIGHT, Pieces.ROOK};
    board[1] = new Pieces[]{Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN};;
    board[board.length - 2] = new Pieces[]{Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN, Pieces.PAWN};;
}
```